# Error while restoring Site Collection to the same server

Tags: 2010, stsadm, spsite

I am trying to restore a site (`http://server:7457`) to another site (`http://server:80`) on the same server.

I had took the backup of the first site using SharePoint Administration Central. When I restore the backup I am getting an error saying "Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint  Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version '4.0.145.0' or later."

I've tried the below commands.

`Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://server" -path "C:\28-04-2014\Site1.bak" -Force`

`STSADM.EXE -o restore -url http://server/ -filename "C:\28-04-2014\Site1.bak" -overwrite`

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please check from the Central admin > upgrade and migration > review the database status check if the database which attached to https://server:7457 required the upgrade? do the same thing with target web application.

Comment: Is it an old backup? If you applied patches (SP or CU) between the backup and the restore, you will get this error message

Comment: how did you take backup of the site,  did you use backup-spsite cmdlet?  Version should not matter since you are trying to restore it on the same server.  are you missing any parameter in the restore command (nofilecompression, includeusersecurity etc)

Answer (score 1):

Check your database version using following

```
 Get-SPContentDatabase <DB name>| Format-List *
```

In this check the SchemaVersionXML if it is "4.0.145.0" then you have to run the below powershell script

```
 **Upgrade-SPContentDatabse –Identity <DB Name>
```

and then take fresh back up and try.